# str.split() memory consumption

Tags: python, memory-management

I'm having difficulties with managing memory consumption of `str.split()`.
It looks like it is consuming few times more memory than I would expect

Compare following scripts:

```
import memory_profiler
t= [str.split("one two three four five") for l in range(50000000)]
memory_profiler.memory_usage()
```

`[21748.140625]`

And the benchmark for just storing such list:

```
import memory_profiler
t= [["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"] for l in range(50000000)]
memory_profiler.memory_usage()
```

`[5468.6015625]`

My python version is:

```
3.6.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul 20 2017, 13:51:32) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
```

Just a note: I need the data in memory for later processing (it has to be in memory so I can use multiple workers) so using a generator is not a solution. The whole dataset fits perfectly in memory at least 3 times yet I need to split it to list of words.

Comment: have you tried to call the garbage collector before invoking the profiler? I can't reproduce here. I don't have `memory_profiler` handy.

Comment: Even: `import memory_profiler
t= [[w for w in "one two three four five"] for l in range(50000000)]
memory_profiler.memory_usage()`
consumes less memory: [13296.5859375]

Comment: What happens if you move this to a `for` loop?

Comment: Invoking gc.collect() frees no memory.

Comment: Or doing `"one two three four five".split()` instead of calling `str.split()`?

Comment: Moving it to `for` loop destroys performance. And having to `.appen()` is not a good idea either. See: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops

Comment: How do you know this? If you're building huge objects in memory with the list comp, how can that run faster? Just because general notes say that list comprehensions are more efficient doesn't always make it so.